# Change/ refresh permalink after restoring the page from trash

Tags: wordpress, frontend

I am working on a multilangual wordpress site, by accident I have moved to trash my english front page, and after I have restored from the bin the permalink has http://o3zone.demo.enetixsoftware.ro/en/__trashed-6/ --> this trashed ending, how can I remove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Ndy i have checked your website and go through
url you have provided.
I think trashed url is crawled by google so you have to manually set 301 redirection in .htaccess file like below.
Open .htaccess file and put below code underneath # END WordPress.

```
Redirect 301 : /en/__trashed-6/ /en/
```

I hope it will work